# Alternative for JVM Flags of Java 8 in Java 11

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I have been using the following flags in my application using Java 8:-

1) PrintFLSStatistics=1

2) +PrintPromotionFailure

3) -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps

4) -XX:+PrintGCDetails

I have been moving the application to use Java 11 instead of Java 8. It seems these flags are either deprecated or not supported in Java 11. Please tell the alternatives of these flags in Java 11.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: These flags are specific to GC while moving from 8 to 11 changes default GC algo to G1 (this was done in 9). You might be comparing apples to oranges and it's impossible to tell if you don't provide GC config.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 11, you have to use `-Xlog` instead. For example: `java -Xlog:gc\*::time -jar my.jar` will log something like

```
[2020-02-19T18:32:50.107-0300] Heap region size: 1M
[2020-02-19T18:32:50.119-0300] Using G1
[2020-02-19T18:32:50.119-0300] Heap address: 0x000000070a200000, size: 3934 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
```

> -Xlog is the general logging configuration option for logging in the HotSpot JVM. It's a tag-based system where gc is one of the tags. To
>   get more information about what a GC is doing, you can configure
>   logging to print any message that has the gc tag and any other tag.
>   The command line option for this is -Xlog:gc*.

See:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/garbage-collector-implementation.html#GUID-A24775AB-16A3-4B86-9963-76E5AC398A3E

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In https://dzone.com/articles/disruptive-changes-to-gc-logging-in-java-9, the equivalent jar option for +PrintPromotionFailure flag is  -Xlog:gc+ promotion=debug is specified. Whether java -Xlog:gc\*::time -jar my.jar will also include the task performed by PrintFLSStatistics=1 and +PrintPromotionFailure flags.